Could primordial black holes have been supermassive?
Usually when primordial black holes are mentioned, they are imagined to be tiny. Could they have been supermassive? This would explain the existence of quasars in early universe.

Hooper et al. (2024) address exactly this possibility. They explore the requirements to produce a population of "primordial" supermassive black holes from density perturbations during the time between the epoch of nucleosynthesis but whilst the universe is radiation dominated.
They conclude that it is only possible, given the constraints on the spectrum of density fluctuations supplied by the cosmic microwave background, if the distribution of perturbations had significantly non-Gaussian "heavy tails".
They discuss a speculative inflationary model that might provide that non-Gaussianity.

The quoted study is valid only if the CMB represents the last scattering surface. However, the “Axis of Evil” evidence suggests that this is not the case and that the observed CMB actually is specific to our current location in the universe. In other words, CMB likely represents the light of our own group of galaxies after making a full circle around the closed universe. Still the conclusions of the study seem valid in a broader sense that super massive black holes could not have been just randomly created +1

"In other words, CMB likely represents the light of our own group of galaxies after making a full circle around the closed universe"- Quite the claim! I don't think "likely" is a fair descriptor of this scenario given current data...
